# Android Activity freezes some seconds in a 1GB RAM device before it opens

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, ram

I have an activity that is called from MainActivity when an Image Button is pressed. I use a Thread.

```
ImageButton btnQuiz = findViewById(R.id.bQuiz);
btnQuiz.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // a potentially time consuming task
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Quiz.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }).start();
});
```

When I press that button in any AVD device it works propertly, but when I run it on my old tablet with Android 4.4.4 and 1GB or RAM memory, it freezes some seconds and I can read in the debug window of Android Studio:

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3528K, 47% free 4367K/8176K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 748K, 50% free 4148K/8176K, paused 12ms, total 12ms  
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 405K, 48% free 4254K/8176K, paused 12ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 426K, 47% free 4340K/8176K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 422K, 46% free 4438K/8176K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 436K, 45% free 4555K/8176K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 491K, 44% free 4657K/8176K, paused 14ms, total 22ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 495K, 42% free 4787K/8176K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 526K, 40% free 4931K/8176K, paused 15ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 594K, 39% free 5054K/8176K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 622K, 37% free 5190K/8176K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 637K, 35% free 5357K/8176K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 705K, 33% free 5511K/8176K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 732K, 31% free 5689K/8176K, paused 18ms, total 23ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 787K, 29% free 5872K/8176K, paused 18ms, total 22ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 255K, 28% free 5911K/8176K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.548MB for 4016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 28% free 5920K/8180K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.556MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5923K/8184K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.558MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 28% free 5922K/8188K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.558MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 28% free 5929K/8192K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.565MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5932K/8196K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.568MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 28% free 5936K/8200K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.572MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 67K, 28% free 5950K/8204K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.585MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5953K/8208K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.588MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 28% free 5959K/8212K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.595MB for 4016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5963K/8216K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.599MB for 4016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 129K, 28% free 5979K/8220K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.614MB for 2940-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 28% free 5981K/8224K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.616MB for 4016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5984K/8228K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 6.620MB for 4016-byte allocation
```

This is the layout that is loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.geologyapplications.minerals.Quiz"
android:theme="@android:style/Holo.Light.ButtonBar"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_tipo"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/tipo2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_diafanidad"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="@string/diafanidad2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:focusable="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_grupo"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/grupo2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_brillo"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="@string/brillo2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:focusable="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_clase"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/clase2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_raya"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="@string/raya2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:focusable="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_formula"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/formula2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_dureza"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="@string/dureza2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:focusable="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_sistema"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/sistema2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_densidad"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="@string/densidad2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:focusable="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_ambientes"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/ambientes2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_exfoliacion"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/exfoliacion2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_habito"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/habito2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_fractura"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/fractura2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/color2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="@string/numpreguntas"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
            </TextView>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/numpreguntas"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
                android:autofillHints="10"
                android:hint="@string/diez">
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:id="@+id/empezar"
                android:text="@string/empezar"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/white">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:id="@+id/iratienda"
                android:text="@string/iratienda"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I can't post the Java class as it has 500 lines, but you can read it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1br63bDZXGtqotDPQHLyYyzfOBPR9WcU4/view?usp=sharing).

My question is if there is something wrong in my code or just my app should have as requisite 2GB of RAM and set the minimumSDKVersion to Android 5.0.

Have I managed incorrectly the threads?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your layout is too complex with lots of nested layouts. Try to split your XML by moving pieces to separate layout files and then add them using the `<include>` tab, each of these `<include>` layouts will be inflated in a different call. Another option could be to see if you can make your screen design work with a RecyclerView.

The main idea is to split the inflation of each of your view components into different screen frames. Heavy operations that take longer than 16ms will freeze a few frames.